# networkadapter returns ipv6 adress, ssh command fails

Tags: docker, ipv6, hyper-v

I wanted to run a docker container at work following these instructions:

https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#environment-variables-and-default-values

when I run `docker-machine -D create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "minikube" --hyperv-cpu-count "1" --hyperv-memory "1024" --hyperv-disk-size "20000" worker4`

docker is stuck and repeats this step further and further:

```
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(worker4) Calling .GetSSHHostname
(worker4) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive ( Get-VM worker4 ).state
(worker4) DBG | [stdout =====>] : Running
(worker4) DBG |
(worker4) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(worker4) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive (( Get-VM worker4 ).networkadapters[0]).ipaddresses[0]
(worker4) DBG | [stdout =====>] : fe80::215:5dff:fe0a:2b3d
(worker4) DBG |
(worker4) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(worker4) Calling .GetSSHPort
(worker4) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(worker4) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(worker4) Calling .GetSSHUsername
Using SSH client type: external
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@fe80::215:5dff:fe0a:2b3d -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Use
rs\account\.docker\machine\machines\worker4\id_rsa -p 22] C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe <nil>}
```

I tried the same steps at home (both systems with Windows 10) and it succeed. After comparing the logs I found out, that I got a local ipv4 adress at home. We are using only ipv4 at work so I am confused why I got an ipv6 address. Could this be the error why it got stuck?

**Update:**

After I removed git bash and run the command again, I got this error:

```
Error dialing TCP: dial tcp [fe80::215:5dff:fe0a:2b47]:22: connectex: Ein Socketvorgang bezog sich auf ein nicht verfügbares Netzwerk.
```

According to Microsoft the Network is unreachable. Can it be that my network card is miss configured or maybe that the router has some problems?

Comment: See if this helps https://tristanwatkins.com/disabling-ipv6/

Comment: @TarunLalwani: The value is already set in the registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the ip adresses from our network are static ones.

1. Create minikube in an dynamic network
2. `minikube stop`
3. Connect your pc to your static network and give the minikube vm a mac address that can has a connected ip address
4. `minikube start`